# loopback find Users based on they Role

Tags: relationship, loopbackjs

Is there a way to get all Users with the same Role?

Now i only can think at doing this using multiple steps.
I have to get the Role first, then all the RollMappings, parse them and get the principalId and then get all Users.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are dynamic roles and static roles. For example, $everyone, $authenticated, $owner are dynamic roles and the isInRole is determined per request. For static roles, the user/role mapping is stored at RoleMapping model. You should be able find all users for a given role at:

`RoleMapping.find({where: {principalType: ‘USER’, principalId: userId, roleId: roleId}, cb);`

Comment: Thank you, i knew this answer. I wanted another method. I guess i can extend the User model and add a direct relation to Role.